# initWithContentsOfURL suddenly gives a "deprecated" error

Tags: iphone, ios5, xcode4.2, initwithcontentsofurl

I just opened my project in the new XCode 4.2 for the first time and I'm suddenly getting a whole slew of these warnings:  'initWithContentsOfURL:' is deprecated

Here's the code - anyone know what needs to be fixed here? (it was working perfectly fine in XCode 4.0)

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{

    NSURL *modelURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"TermsConditions" withExtension:@"html"];
    NSString *myHtml = [[NSString alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:modelURL];
    [self.TermsWebView loadHTMLString:myHtml baseURL:modelURL];
    [myHtml release];
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use the method initWithContentsOfURL:usedEncoding:error:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{ 

    NSURL *modelURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"TermsConditions" withExtension:@"html"];

    NSStringEncoding *encoding;
    NSError *error;

    NSString *myHtml = [[NSString alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:modelURL usedEncoding:&encoding error:&error];
    [self.TermsWebView loadHTMLString:myHtml baseURL:modelURL];
    [myHtml release];
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.
}
```

Comment: I tried your code and I'm getting this warning now: "incompatible integer to pointer conversion sending 'int' to parameter of type NSStringEncoding". Any ideas?

Comment: I finally had a chance to drop this is into Xcode.  I made a few small changes above.  In this case, it determines the encoding for you - so you need to pass in a pointer to a variable of type of NSStringEncoding.  After you fetch the data, this variable will be populated with the encoding of the file at the URL.

Comment: that sorta worked. I still got warnings when I typed it as you suggested above, so I tweaked til it worked. I didn't & still don't understand what the '&' in front of 'encoding' and 'error' is all about (why are we using an '&' here? I've only seen '&' used in a 'scanf' statement...) - so I tweaked that. The warning-free version of the code I finally came up with is: **NSString *myHtml = [[NSString alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:modelURL usedEncoding:encoding error:&error];**  So there's no '&' in front of 'encoding', and there IS an '&' in front if 'error' . Don't ask me y or how - it works :-)

Comment: The issue is that NSStringEncoding is an integer.  So you need to drop the asterisk in this line of code: "NSStringEncoding *encoding;"

Answer (score 1):

When you get a message that a given method is deprecated, check [the documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html) for information. In this case, you'll find that `-initWithContentsOfURL:` is no longer listed on the NSString reference page.

Another useful resource is the header file for the class in question. If you check NSString.h, you'll find:

```
- (id)initWithContentsOfURL:(NSURL *)url DEPRECATED_IN_MAC_OS_X_VERSION_10_4_AND_LATER;
```

Comment: thank you for this. I do see it in the docs. However, when calling 'initWithContentsOfURL:usedEncoding:error:'  I'm not sure what to pass into the 'usedEncoding' parameter. The suggestion made in the other reply to my question produces a warning. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

That method has been deprecated and replaced by

initWithContentsOfURL:enconding:error

or

initWithContentsOfURL:usedEnconding:error

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Try this out it seems to be error free

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
```

{

```
NSURL *modelURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"TermsConditions" withExtension:@"html"];

NSStringEncoding *encoding = NULL;
NSError *error;

NSString *myHtml = [[NSString alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:modelURL usedEncoding:encoding error:&error];
[self.TermsWebView loadHTMLString:myHtml baseURL:modelURL];
[myHtml release];
[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.
```

}

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be the correct code:

> NSStringEncoding *encoding = NULL;
>   NSString *jsonReturn = [[NSString alloc]initWithContentsOfURL:url encoding:*encoding error:NULL];

The warnings will be eliminated only if ,
1.you initialise encoding to NULL.
2.Put a * before encoding.